# How to create json object with key and value, where value is array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I need to make json object with key, and value, where value is array of values. How could i do that ?

```
{"propName" : "favouriteObjectsIds", 
 "value": [
        "5c93f4cc3a6565000483248d",
        "5c93f7843a6565000483248e"
        ] 
}
```

I have tried like this

```
public void add(String propertyName, String[] values){
        JsonArray array1 = new JsonArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            array.add(values[i]);
        }

        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("propName", propertyName);
        json.addProperty("value" ,array.toString());
    }
```

but array.toString() gives me such output

```
{"propName":"favouriteObjectsIds",
"value":"[\"5c93f4cc3a6565000483248d\",\"5c9b82ad24b33b0004227322\"]"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.add` instead of `.addProperty` for JsonElements

```
public void add(String propertyName, String[] values){

    JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        array.add(values[i]);
    }

    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("propName", propertyName);
    json.add("value" ,array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can build you json with ArrayList like this :

```
public void add(String propertyName,ArrayList<String> list){

        Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
        map.put("propName", propertyName);
        map.put("value", list);


         JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(map);
     //  convert JSONObject to JSON to String
         String  json = jObject.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the examples above create two properties, each with a key(name) and a value.  The first property key is "propName" which has the value of "favouriteObjectsIds", the second property key is "value" which has the value of "["5c93f4cc3a6565000483248d","5c93f7843a6565000483248e"]"

I suspect that you would rather have this:

```
{"favouriteObjectsIds": [
    "5c93f4cc3a6565000483248d",
    "5c93f7843a6565000483248e"
    ] 
}
```

If that is true, you could do so in this way:

```
String myJson = "{\"favouriteObjectsIds\":[\"5c93f4cc3a6565000483248d\",\"5c93f7843a6565000483248e\"]}"; 

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(myJson );

JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("favouriteObjectsIds");
```

Comment: no, that's not the case. I need such json format, becouse my rest api takes such one for patch method, but thanks for response .